# Convert oid to json as int instead of string

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 12, the following will return an int JSON representation:

```
> SELECT to_json(2::int)
.. 2
```

Whereas if the type is `oid`, it will return it as string:

```
> SELECT to_json(2::oid)
.. "2"
```

Since oid is inherently an int value, I would like it to be represented as such. I tried creating a cast between `oid` and both `text` and `json` types, but neither seems to be picked up by `to_json`.

Is there a way to make `to_json` represent an `oid` as an `int`, outside of casting each oid column to int explicitly?

Comment: Why are you using OIDs to begin with?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm developing a project that deals a lot with pg's metadata in pg_catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an explicit cast, because it is hard-coded that PostgreSQL treats `oid` as a string.

You could suggest the following patch to the pgsql-hackers mailing list:

```
diff --git a/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c b/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c
index 30ca2cf6c8..09e9a9ac08 100644
--- a/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c
+++ b/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c
@@ -170,6 +170,7 @@ json_categorize_type(Oid typoid,
        case FLOAT4OID:
        case FLOAT8OID:
        case NUMERICOID:
+       case OIDOID:
            getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
            *tcategory = JSONTYPE_NUMERIC;
            break;
diff --git a/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c b/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c
index 8d1e7fbf91..0e8edb0fc3 100644
--- a/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c
+++ b/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c
@@ -650,6 +650,7 @@ jsonb_categorize_type(Oid typoid,
        case FLOAT4OID:
        case FLOAT8OID:
        case NUMERICOID:
+       case OIDOID:
            getTypeOutputInfo(typoid, outfuncoid, &typisvarlena);
            *tcategory = JSONBTYPE_NUMERIC;
            break;
```

That would change the behavior, and I don't see why the patch shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: While I'm not sure I will be posting a patch proposal (besides, it's yours!), I was able to make it work on my dev instance where I need it to work like that, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can override to_json by creating a function with the same name in public schema that does the casting for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.to_json(IN prm oid) RETURNS json 
LANGUAGE SQL AS
$body$
  SELECT pg_catalog.to_json(prm::int);
$body$;
```

Comment: That'd only work for this one param, I need it to work when I'm doing something like `SELECT to_json(typ.*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_type typ`